# ITextSharp signing PDF/A document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdfa

So I am trying to sign a PDF/A-1A document, the document was generated using ITextSharp. When i Sign the document and try to verify the document i get the following errors,

> Validating file "test_pdfA_compliance_signed.pdf" for conformance level pdfa-1a
>   The required XMP property 'pdfaid:part' is missing.
>   The required XMP property 'pdfaid:conformance' is missing.
>   A string is longer than 65535 bytes.
>   The document does not conform to the requested standard.
>   The document doesn't conform to the PDF reference (missing required entries, wrong value types, etc.).
>   The document's meta data is either missing or inconsistent or corrupt.
>   Done.

Document Pre-Signed: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9RyqgJoa6W8UDFSeHJSX09QamM/view?usp=sharing

Document Post-Signed: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9RyqgJoa6W8Y3lGbFU4a2RsLWc/view?usp=sharing

But the signing process is completed as expected, but what i have realised was that if I test whether the document claims to be PDF/A compliant it fails as if there is not metadata claiming PDF/A,

```
private bool CreatePdfStamperIsPDFADocument(PdfReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.Metadata != null && reader.Metadata.Length > 0)
        {
            IXmpMeta xmpMeta = XmpMetaParser.Parse(reader.Metadata, null);
            IXmpProperty pdfaidConformance = xmpMeta.GetProperty(XmpConst.NS_PDFA_ID, "pdfaid:conformance");
            IXmpProperty pdfaidPart = xmpMeta.GetProperty(XmpConst.NS_PDFA_ID, "pdfaid:part");

            if (pdfaidConformance == null || pdfaidPart == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The code i used to sign the document, the PDF stamper used here is the normal one since the check fails. When i try to use the PDFAStamper it complains saying that only PDF/A documents can be used.

```
private byte[] SignDocument(Certificate certificate, SigningInformation information, List<SigningBlock> signingBlocks, List<MemberItemSignature> signatureImages, byte[] document, bool certify)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < signingBlocks.Count; i++)
        {
            using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(document))
                {
                    using (PdfStamper stamper = CreatePdfStamper(reader, outputStream, true))
                    {
                        SigningBlock signingBlock = signingBlocks[i];
                        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = CreatePdfAppearance(stamper, information, certify && i == 0);

                        SignDocumentSigningBlock(certificate, information, signingBlock, appearance, stamper, GetSignatureImage(signatureImages, signingBlock.Name));
                    }
                }

                document = outputStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return document;
    }
```

So this is the code where i determine which PDF stamper to use, but this is where it fails since the document im using is returning null for both components I use to determine PDF/A claim,

```
        private PdfStamper CreatePdfStamper(PdfReader reader, MemoryStream outputStream, bool isSignature)
    {
        if (isSignature)
        {
            if (CreatePdfStamperIsPDFADocument(reader))
            {
                return PdfAStamper.CreateSignature(reader, outputStream, _pdfVersion, null, true, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A);
            }
            else
            {
                return PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, outputStream, _pdfVersion, null, true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream, _pdfVersion, true);
        }
    }
```

Am I doing something stupid or missing something small?
Thank you for any help.

Kind regards

Comment: Consider using PDF/A specific iTextSharp classes like `PdfAStamper`. You might have to add a dependency on the PDF/A related iTextSharp companion library.

Comment: I do use the PDF/A specific classes the problem being that the PdfAStamper throws an exception stating that it is not a PDF/A document that im trying to load. I investigated why, and in the code sample pdfaidConformance as well as pdfaidpart is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the regular `PdfStamper`, iTextSharp does not make an attempt to make your output file PDF/A compliant. In particular, it will not add any PDF/A related metadata. So it's expected that your test on the metadata (`CreatePdfStamperIsPDFADocument()`) returns `false` for the signed document.

When running that code sample on your input file, it returns `true`, with `pdfaidPart` equal to `1` and `pdfaidConformance` equal to `A`. This is what the debugger shows while running the code:

[image: pdfaid values]

To get a PDF/A output file, you have to use `PdfAStamper`. You say that `PdfAStamper` gives you an error about your input file not being PDF/A. This could be because you are specifying a different PDF/A part and/or conformance level than your input file. `PdfAStamper` will not convert a PDF/A input file to a different part or conformance level.

So make sure you create the `PdfAStamper` for PDF/A-1a input:

```
PdfStamper stamper = PdfAStamper.CreateSignature(reader, outputfile,
    '\0', PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A);
```

Comment: mmm thats really weird, for me it returns null for both of the components i.e. pdfaidPart & pdfaidConformance. So I am using the PDFAStamper and ive updated the question with the relevant code snippet. From the code snippet you can see that I do a check that if it is a PDF/A document it uses the PDFAStamper, otherwise uses the normal stamper, But for me the if statement fails which is where my problem is. I am using ITextSharp 5.5.6 due to the signing bug in 5.5.7

Comment: I have tested again with your exact code samples, your *Pre-Signed* PDF and iTextSharp 5.5.6. Behaviour is still as expected. I'll update my answer with a debugger screen shot.

Comment: I dont know what my VisualStudio was doing but today when i ran the exact same code as yesterday the code worked as expected and i got the same result as you did. Only difference is i restarted my VS, dont know what was going on there :O.Thanks for the response and help :)